# Convert Integer To Date in Java

Tags: java, date, date-format, localdate, datetimeformatter

I Have Integer a = 30;

how to i convert Date 30 every month.

example

Integer a = 25;
25/01/2021
25/02/2021
25/03/2021

or

Integer a = 10;
10/01/2021
10/02/2021
10/03/2021

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a loop to run `12` times (one for each month). Start with the month, `1` and the specified day-of-month. In each iteration, print the date, and increment the month by `1` for the next iteration.

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int x = 10;
        LocalDate start = LocalDate.now().withMonth(1).withDayOfMonth(x);
        for (int i = 1; i <= 12; i++, start = start.plusMonths(1)) {
            System.out.println(start.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/uuuu")));
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
10/01/2021
10/02/2021
10/03/2021
10/04/2021
10/05/2021
10/06/2021
10/07/2021
10/08/2021
10/09/2021
10/10/2021
10/11/2021
10/12/2021
```

Learn more about the date-time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [LocalDate#of](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#of-int-java.time.Month-int-) and [LocalDate#plusMonths](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#plusMonths-long-)

```
int day = 31;
int months = 3;

LocalDate firstDate = LocalDate.of(2021, 1, day);

List<LocalDate> dates = IntStream.range(0, months)
        .mapToObj(firstDate::plusMonths)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

This would output these dates:

```
2021-01-31
2021-02-28
2021-03-31
```